# No internet connection after using iptables

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

I'm running Debian via VMware and I've setup these rules with iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Now I can't access any websites through firefox. I tried running iptables -F but it's still the same for some reason. Is there something wrong with the rules perhaps?

Comment: Were you able to connect prior to running the script? What happens if you run `iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT`? Are you able to connect then?

Comment: Can you post the output of `iptables -L` when you cannot connect?

Comment: @OnkelJ Yes it worked fine before I ran the script. iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani This is the output: https://i.imgur.com/mmWgKdD.png

Comment: I don't see anything that could block Firefox from accessing the network. Do other browsers work?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Unfortunately firefox is the only one I have installed, I can't download anything with apt-get neither so it seems like the whole network is down.